# SciDraw Ticks not working?

Tags: ticks, scidraw

I'm using SciDraw to make an array of ContourPlots, but my attempt to use XTicks and YTicks isn't working. Why?

Note that I need to keep the creation of plots separate from the rest of the code (because in my use case I'm receiving the plots from someone else).

```
plots = Table[
   ContourPlot[Cos[n x] Cos[n y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}], {n, 1, 4}];

dims = {2, 2};

(*init SciDraw first!*)

DefineStyle["SOSArray", {
  FigurePanel -> {
    XTicks -> {-1, 0, 1}, YTicks -> {-1, 0, 1},
    XPlotRange -> {-1, 1}, YPlotRange -> {-1, 1}
    }
  }]

Figure[
 Multipanel[{
   FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[plots[[1]]]}, {1, 1}];
   FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[plots[[2]]]}, {1, 2}];
   FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[plots[[3]]]}, {2, 1}];
   FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[plots[[4]]]}, {2, 2}];
   },
  Dimensions -> dims]
 , Style -> "SOSArray", CanvasSize -> {1, dims[[1]]/dims[[2]]}*5]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ticks are there, just without labels. If you want to have labeled ticks, you need to use the `LinTicks` function of `SciDraw`. In the example below I use your ticks definition for the y axis (note the small ticks every 0.5 units) and `LinTicks` for the x axis:

```
(* LinTicks can be made more visible *)

SetOptions[LinTicks, MajorTickLength -> {0.04, 0}, 
  MajorTickStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[2], Black}];

DefineStyle["SOSArray", {FigurePanel -> {XTicks -> 
     LinTicks[-1, 1, 1, 1], YTicks -> {-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1}, 
    XPlotRange -> {-1, 1}, YPlotRange -> {-1, 1}}}]

Figure[Multipanel[{FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[plots[[1]]]}, {1, 1}];
   FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[plots[[2]]]}, {1, 2}];
   FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[plots[[3]]]}, {2, 1}];
   FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[plots[[4]]]}, {2, 2}];}, 
  Dimensions -> dims], Style -> "SOSArray", 
 CanvasSize -> {1, dims[[1]]/dims[[2]]}*5]
```

[image]